# Python Cherrypy Access Log Rotation

Tags: python, cherrypy, logging

If I want the access log for Cherrypy to only get to  a fixed size, how would I go about using rotating log files?

I've already tried http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/Logging, which seems out of date, or has information missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html.

You probably want to configure a RotatingFileHandler

http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#rotatingfilehandler

Answer (score 3):

> I've already tried http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/Logging, which seems 
>   out of date, or has information missing.

Try adding:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import cherrypy # you might have imported this already
```

and instead of

```
log = app.log
```

maybe try

```
log = cherrypy.log
```

Answer (score 3):

The CherryPy documentation of the [custom log handlers](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.html#custom-handlers) shows this very example.

Here is the slightly modified version that I use on my app:

```
import logging
from logging import handlers

def setup_logging():

    log = cherrypy.log

    # Remove the default FileHandlers if present.
    log.error_file = ""
    log.access_file = ""

    maxBytes = getattr(log, "rot_maxBytes", 10000000)
    backupCount = getattr(log, "rot_backupCount", 1000)

    # Make a new RotatingFileHandler for the error log.
    fname = getattr(log, "rot_error_file", "log\\error.log")
    h = handlers.RotatingFileHandler(fname, 'a', maxBytes, backupCount)
    h.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    h.setFormatter(cherrypy._cplogging.logfmt)
    log.error_log.addHandler(h)

    # Make a new RotatingFileHandler for the access log.
    fname = getattr(log, "rot_access_file", "log\\access.log")
    h = handlers.RotatingFileHandler(fname, 'a', maxBytes, backupCount)
    h.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    h.setFormatter(cherrypy._cplogging.logfmt)
    log.access_log.addHandler(h)

setup_logging()
```

Answer (score 2):

Cherrypy does its logging using the standard Python logging module. You will need to change it to use a [RotatingFileHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#rotatingfilehandler). This handler will take care of everything for you including rotating the log when it reaches a set maximum size.