# cherrypy: python how to create separate request log files for everyday with the help of log rotator

Tags: python, python-2.7, cherrypy

i want to create seperate log file for access and error in cherrypy.
 i read http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/_cplogging.html , but i am not getting to write code to implement logging.

i read on more link [Python Cherrypy Access Log Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601665/python-cherrypy-access-log-rotation).

plz provide code and document how to implement logging in cherrypy
plz help me out by providing a sample code

i hv one hello.py file

import cherrypy

class HelloWorld:
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world!"
    index.exposed = True

```
@cherrypy.expose
def link(self):
    #print HelloWorld.c

    #print self.j
    return "link"

@cherrypy.expose
def link2(self):
    return "link2"
```

if **name** == '**main**' :
    cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())

whats changes are needed to implement logging
please provide code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
import logging
from cherrypy import _cplogging
from logging import handlers
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld:
    @cherrypy.expose 
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world!" 

    @cherrypy.expose
    def link(self):
        #print HelloWorld.c

        #print self.j
        return "link"

    @cherrypy.expose
    def link2(self):
        return "link2"

if name == 'main' :
    applicationLogFileHandler = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('rot_access_file', "midnight", 1)
    applicationLogFileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    applicationLogFileHandler.setFormatter(_cplogging.logfmt)
    cherrypy.log.access_log.addHandler(applicationLogFileHandler)

    applicationLogFileHandler = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('rot_error_file', "midnight", 1)
    applicationLogFileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    applicationLogFileHandler.setFormatter(_cplogging.logfmt)
    cherrypy.log.error_log.addHandler(applicationLogFileHandler)

    cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: suppose there is one hello.py file with class root and mwthods as index, link,page...then i will hv to write another file for logging..

Comment: No - you should not have to write another.  I've updated my answer with your code.

Comment: this code works fine..according to my project i need some more modification 1] i need to create separate request log files for everyday with the help of log rotator 2] file should be stored in any folder named src...plz provide code with necessary changes requirement

Comment: Ah I understand. You want TimedRotatingFileHandler I've updated my code.

Comment: i checked its creating new log file everyday

Comment: suppose in any function has print statements..for example def link(self): handler has print "link" statement..when we call this handler it prints link on chrerrypy console screen...now if i want to record those print statements..what changes i will have to make in above code which you gave..

Comment: when there is error error log file record every statements of cherrypy console screen..but in accesss file it shows only handler called for example  "127.0.0.1 - - [26/Sep/2013:10:03:13] "POST /link HTTP/1.1" 500 1319 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0" is recorded in access file ... but i want that it should record. "link
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Sep/2013:12:28:00] "GET /link HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0" as i m printing link through print "link" statement in    def link():